# Convert Pandas Dataframe to a nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

So I have this pandas data frame like:
UserName SchoolID Age Weight Height RankInClass
What I want to do is:
make a dictionary with key Username
and a subdictionary with key School ID
The sub dictionary will have a list as the values (age, weight, height, rank)
Can someone please guide how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

okay first create the sub data frame you need to create let's say the name of that data frame variable is `data` and convert it from the pandas inbuilt function

```
data_dict = data.to_dict()
```

it will work

Comment: Okay, this will make the bigger dictionary. How to make the sub dictionaries now?

Comment: STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ID, AGE, HEIGHT, WEIGHT, RANK_IN_CLASS

Now I want the student name to be the key to the bigger dictionary.. then a smaller dictionary with student id as the key and the value will be the list age, height, rank etc.